# rails functional testing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, functional-testing

When I do

```
get :inside, :format => :xml, :lat2 => "41", :lng2 => "-73.9", :lat1 => "40", :lng1 => "-74", :category => "girl", :order => "date"
```

with my routes.rb includes:

```
get 'images/inside/:lat1/:lng1/:lat2/:lng2/:order/:category', :to => "images#inside"
```

I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:lng1=>"-74", :category=>"girl", :lat2=>"41", :format=>:xml, :lng2=>"-73.9", :order=>"date", :lat1=>"40", :action=>"inside", :controller=>"images"}
```

But when I do

```
get :inside, :format => :xml, :lat2 => "41", :lng2 => "-73", :lat1 => "40", :lng1 => "-74", :category => "girl", :order => "date"
```

it works!

The only difference is the decimal value of lng2.

Note that if routes.rb has no params, it works, but I need those

Comment: beware of your params, it seems you are inverting category and order

Comment: btw you should url_encode your params.

Comment: Order does not matter in a hash, and as far as I know, rails is taking in the url encoding in this case. plus, url_encode(".") === ".", so that would not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's because your value has a period. By default, Rails (at least Rails3) routes cannot contain periods. To work around this, see http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/06/18/rails-3-resource-routes-with-dots-or-how-to-make-a-ruby-developer-go-a-little-bit-insane/

Comment: totally makes sense, looks like I was a bit too much inside my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I bet the decimal point is making Rails think that there's a format being specified (e.g. .xml or .js).

You might be able to get around it using a regex, something like what's described here: http://zargony.com/2009/05/05/routing-parameters-with-a-dot